# Length of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

This function is generating a array with json objects on it:

```
var estoque={};
function unpack_estoque(tnm,total,estoque_vl,id,tid,st) {
    tnm=tnm.split("|");
    total=total.split("|");
    estoque_vl=estoque_vl.split("|");
    id=typeof id != 'undefined' ? id.split("|") : null;
    tid=typeof tid != 'undefined' ? tid.split("|") : null;
    st=typeof st != 'undefined' ? st.split("|") : null;

    for (var i in tnm)
        estoque[i]={
            "id": id != null ? id[i] : null,
            "tid": tid != null ? tid[i] : null,
            "total": total[i],
            "estoque": estoque_vl[i],
            "tnm": tnm[i],
            "st": st != null ? st[i] : null
        };
}
```

Now how do i get the `estoque` length to loop through the collected items?

`estoque.length` returns `undefined` while `for (var i in estoque)` loops through JSON object and not estoque[] root array.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5223/104380

Comment: Forget all those complex methods, use this: `Object.keys(estoque).length`

Comment: Great method Derek! Though, let it be noted that this method isn't compatible with IE 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var estoque = {}; //object estoque.length will not work (length is an array function)
var estoque = new Array(); //estoque.length will work
```

You could try:

```
 var estoque = new Array();
 for (var i in tnm)
    estoque.push({
        "id": id != null ? id[i] : null,
        "tid": tid != null ? tid[i] : null,
        "total": total[i],
        "estoque": estoque_vl[i],
        "tnm": tnm[i],
        "st": st != null ? st[i] : null
    });
```

Now estoque will be an array (which you can traverse as one).

Answer (score 1):

You will not get that to work as it is an array method, not an object. You can use the length property of tnm as your measure. Then you can you can use:

```
var tnmLength = tnm.length;
for (i=0, i>tnmLength - 1; i++) {
     estoque[tnm[i]] = {};
}
```

To loop through all of the items in the tnm array.

Answer (score 1):

```
a={a:{},b:{},c:{}}
Object.keys(a).length
3
```