# JS object access

Tags: javascript

I have a js object and i'm trying to access it directly without having to do something like :

```
for(i in data) { obj = data[i] }
```

is there a better way to access this object without looping ? (i'll always have  1 result)

here is the firebug result for console.log(data) :

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `data[8][8]`? what a key name!

Comment: Are you aware of the key name that you want to access before trying to loop?

Comment: no i dont have access to the key name ... this is the user id that i'm returning .

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5533324/538866) answer. `Object.keys[0]` would do it for all browsers, except IE8 and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't access a property without knowing its name (aside from using fancy [for-of-loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)). And to get that name, you only can enumerate the properties with a [for-in-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)/[`….getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).

If you know that you always have exactly one key in your object, you might have chosen the wrong data structure.

Comment: in that specific case yes i get only 1 result because i'm using the same function that return all users .