# How do I check if query string has values in Express.js/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I check if a query string passed to an Express.js application contains any values? If I have an API URL that could be either: `http://example.com/api/objects` or `http://example.com/api/objects?name=itemName`, what conditional statements work to determine which I am dealing with?

My current code is below, and it always evaluates to the 'should have no string' option.

```
if (req.query !== {}) {
    console.log('should have no query string');
}
else {
    console.log('should have query string');
}
```

Comment: Not sure of `node`'s support of this, but maybe you could use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5533226/2708970) to check if the length of `req.query` is greater than 0.

Comment: Are you using express?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

All you need to do is check the length of keys in your `Object`, like this,

```
Object.keys(req.query).length === 0
```

Sidenote: You are implying the if-else in wrong way,

```
if (req.query !== {})     // this will run when your req.query is 'NOT EMPTY', i.e it has some query string.
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that mistake was a typo in converting my real code for the question.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check if there is no query string, you can do a regex search,

```
if (!/\?.+/.test(req.url) {
    console.log('should have no query string');
}
else {
    console.log('should have query string');
}
```

If you are looking for a single param try this

```
if (!req.query.name) {
    console.log('should have no query string');
}
else {
    console.log('should have query string');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use underscore JS [Library](https://underscorejs.org/)

Which has built in function isEmpty(obj). This returns true/false.

So, the code will look like :-

```
const underscore = require('underscore');
console.log(underscore.isEmpty(req.query));
```

Comment: Dude, underscore is long gone. Use lodash.

Answer (score 1):

I usually check if the variable in the query string is defined. Using the url package in ExpressJS it would be so:

```
var aquery = require('url').parse(req.url,true).query;

if(aquery.variable1 != undefined){
  ...
  ....
  var capturedvariablevalue = aquery.variable1;
  ....
  ....

}
else{
  //logic for variable not defined
  ...
  ...
  //
}
```