# How can I get the value from text field in a Fancybox iframe on closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a quiz in a fancybox(2) iframe, when complete I have a score held in a hidden text box on the page within the Fancybox:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" id="theresult" hidden="true"/>
</form>
```

Now when the user closes the Fancybox, I need to capture this value for the parent page to use, I have tried:

```
$('.fancybox1').fancybox({
        width: 800,
        height: 500,    
        beforeClose: function () {
                 var testResult = $("#fancybox-frame").contents().find('input#theresult');
                 $('#txtTestValue').attr('value', testResult );
        }
});
```

But this returns "[object Object]"...

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using fancybox **v2.x** you may need to target the proper *selector* so try this

```
beforeClose : function () {
    var testResult = $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#theresult").val();
    $('#txtTestValue').attr('value', testResult);
}
```

**Notice** the changes :

```
$("#fancybox-frame")
```

... should be

```
$(".fancybox-iframe")
```

... and I also added the `.val()` method.

Comment: If you want to learn a bit more how-to to pass variables back and forth between parent and iframed pages, you may want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/26426934/1055987

Comment: You've hit it right on the head there JFK :-)
Working nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the input field itself. You should be storing the value of the input:

```
var testResult = $("#fancybox-frame").contents().find('input#theresult').val();
```

Comment: thanks - just tried, however now it just returns "0"

Comment: Try with `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Comment: You should post a fiddle of your current setup so we can help you better.