# How to show ajax response in fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, fancybox-2

I have 2 jsp's products.jsp and viewcart.jsp .Now I am trying to show cart(viewcart.jsp) in iframe using fancybox.   When i click add to cart, iframe wont popup. This is what i have done. How should i pass the ajax response to iframe?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.cart').click(function() {
                var pdtid = $(this).attr('data-productid');

                $.ajax({
                    url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addtocart' + pdtid,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type : 'GET',
                    data :{'id': pdtid},
                    success: function(response) {
                        $.fancybox(response,{
                            'width' : 900,
                            'height' : 520,
                            'autoScale' : false,
                            'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                            'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                            'type' : 'iframe',
                            'href' : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/viewcart.html"
                            });
                         }
                      });
                  });
            });
```

**EDIT**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.cart').on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var pdtid = $(this).attr('data-productid');
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      cache: false,
                      url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addtocart' + pdtid,  
                      data: {'id': pdtid}, 
                      success: function (response) {
                          $.fancybox(response,{
                              href : '#response',
                              width: 500,
                              height: 500
                           });
                      }  
                    });  
                  });  
                });
```

Comment: if you do `$.fancybox(response)` you are trying to show a(n) (json) [object], which it won't work. Do you just want to show the `viewcart.jsp` page regardless the `response` you get from ajax? or is there any part from the `response` that affects what you want to show in fancybox?

Comment: I want to add product to viewcart and show it.

Comment: OK, you told me what you want, could you answer specifically my question now?

Comment: Response that affects? I did not get it. No nothing else if i get it right. Do you want controller part or any other part of code.

Comment: Well, the title of your question is confusing. You are asking : "how to show ajax response in fancybox", so I am going to re-formulate my question : what part of the ajax response you want to show?

Comment: I pass request through ajax.Showing product on cart is the response. If there is no need for to pass it through ajax, i will change title.Also i tried keeping fancybox  outside ajax part, it shows iframe, but the product is not added to the iframe cart.

Comment: I guess the issue you are having is because you need to pass `data` to an `iframe`, not just to fancybox. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26446330/1055987 if that helps.

Comment: Okay I will check now.

Comment: @JFK Please check edit. I added a div in the same page to show the cart contents and changed jquery code. Now i am able to load the popup,but contents wont show up on first attempt. If i refresh the page i am able to see the cart contents in the pop up. After long struggle i came this far. Do i need to open new question or it is enough here itself. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Could you tell what does `response` return?

Comment: Name of the product with quantity and price. You need any other part of code.

Comment: If the answer is wrong, i think it returns nothing. Please waste 5 minutes on me, I will learn something. I will not disturb you here after.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer ... I just need to find those 5 minutes to answer your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could try formatting your *ajax* `response` prior parsing it through fancybox like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{your processing file's URL}",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var result =
                "<div id='result'>" +
                "<p>Product Id   : " + response.id + "</p>" +
                "<p>Product Name : " + response.name + "</p>" +
                "</div>";

            $.fancybox(result, {
                type: "html"
            }); // show formated response
        }
    })
}); // ready
```

It's assumed you know the correct (*json*) structure of your `response`.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tqsggp8j/)**

Comment: Thanks for the great help. Just curious, why my edit code in question above works after i refresh only.

Comment: @user3844782 : maybe because you are populating an inline `<div>`, which is empty on page load. I think if you do it as in my example, it should work out of the box

Comment: You may be right. Following your way, i need to change a lot on other parts of the code. But if i am able to make EDIT part code work, it would be easier for me,(if i make it load it without refresh its done). But i don't know if its the right way to do. Can i open a question with more details.