# Loading page fields in a fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, fancybox

I'm not a professional programmer. In a form using asp.net, I have a button which goes to another page in a fancybox using iframe. I want to read one textbox form the parent page and pass it to the next page:

```
<input id="BtnReview" type="button" class="fancyBox" onclick="showFancy('Review.aspx?ordernumber2=' + $('#TxtSaleNumber').val(), 'Review Sale', '85%', '85%');" value="Review Sale" />
```

Then the value of that textbox is used as a parameter to connect to database and available `function[Review(int id)]` and fill the required fields (like textboxes, comboboxes) in the fancybox (the child page). I believe that I need to use `$( document ).ready(function()` and load required fields but I don't know how I can fill the fields.

Comment: This code is not sufficient, please provide code of your child page too.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. The child page is nothing more than a review page with no action. My problem is how to use the passed parameter to fill fields in child page (fancybox) ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/26446330/1055987 if that helps