# Javascript Fancybox pass parameter to popup iframe page

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I am using Fancybox. Type is iframe.

Here's the code:

```
$(".open_iframe").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe'
});
```

On this page I have a variable:

```
var myVar = 'Some Value';
```

What I need to do is to pass myVar to the child page which pop's up.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could also check this if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/26446330/1055987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox serves you a page given a URL to load - you can try and pass a parameter in the link (`GET request`)
and set your routes to deal with it,