# "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid"

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a Google Apps Script that links with a REST API and puts the data into a Google Sheet.

I have successfully done this once, but upon accessing some different data I get the error message

> "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid"

when they work perfectly fine on my other script. All data accessed is JSON so I am bit confused and is from the same source. The code I am using is:

```
function stats () {
  var logIn = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("XXXX" + ':' + "XXXX")
  };

  var url = "XXXXX";
  var params = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":logIn, };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXXX");              

  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dataSet = dataAll;

  var rows = [],
      data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([XXXX]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 1); 
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

I have combined pieces of code from around the web and this works on my other script. The error appears on this line:

```
dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 1);
```

I believe the issue is with the data I am accessing but I do not know how to alter the script for it to work.

The JSON data that works is shown like:

```
{
  id: XXX,
  group: XX,
  text: "XXXX?",
  creation_date: XXXX,
  created_by: "XXXXX",
  tags: [
    "XXXX"
  ]
}
```

And the data that is causing the error is shown as:

```
    {
      2016-02-29: {
      XXX: 0,
      XXX: 0
    },
```

I have had to 'XXXX' out a lot of the private information - apologies. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's length property is for indexed arrays and does not apply to Objects so `dataSet.length` returns `undefined` and the loop never executes.

To get the length of the object you can use `Object.keys(dataSet).length` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length).

Comment: Thank you. I gave this a go and substituted it in. Now it is finishing the script but everything returned is 'undefined' - any ideas?

Comment: What are you pushing in `rows.push([XXXX])`? Are you pushing the whole stringfied JSON object or a part of it? ie e `data.something`?

Comment: I am looking to get the amount of 'Read', if that's possible but data.(anything here) is not picking up the string. 

{
    2016-02-29: {
    Read: 5,
   unread: 0
    },

Comment: Did you try reading it with `data["2016-02-29"]["Read"]`? Are you sure it's `Read` not `read` or `READ`?

Comment: Just tried that and get the following:

TypeError: Cannot read property "2016-02-29" from undefined. 

Sorry yes its all lowercase as 'read' but tried that with the above to no avail.

Comment: So `dataSet` cannot be subscripted using numerical indices. Try calling `dataSet[Object.keys(dataSet)[i]]` instead. That'll iterate through the keys array, pull out the actual key and use that as a subscript of the object.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the first error of: "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid"

Really appreciate the help on this - thank you.

Comment: So just to be sure: `dataAll` is an Object with each element being an an Object of the structure `{"yyyy-mm-dd":{"Read":0, "XXX":0}` Or is `dataAll` itself that object?

Comment: Yes dataAll is an Object with each element being an object of the structure   {"yyyy-mm-dd":{"Read":0, "XXX":0} {"yyyy-mm-dd":{"Read":5, "XXX":5} {"yyyy-mm-dd":{"Read":2, "XXX":3} for example.

Comment: That's weird then as `Object.keys(dataAll)` should be an array of the dates, did you try debugging and seeing if it actually appends the data to rows or where else it has problems?

Comment: As it stands the range that gets entered into the spreadsheet is set up as: 
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 1); 
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

This brings the error mentioned. If I manually change it to:

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1); 
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

I get this error instead on the "dataRange.setValues(rows);" section: Incorrect range height, was 0 but should be 1

Comment: Did you check in the debugger if you actually receive such an Object and that it is properly extracted from from response?

Comment: For dataAll and dataSet I get: 

({'2016-02-29':{read:0, unread}, '2016-03-01':{read:0, unread:0}, '2016-03-02':{read:1, unread:0}, '2016-03-03':{read:1, unread:0}, 

Rows returns []

and 

data returns undefined

Comment: Is your loop `for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataSet).length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[Object.keys(dataSet)[i]];
    rows.push([data.read]); 
  }`?

Comment: Yes it is. 

The error seems all to do with the range section on these lines:

 dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 1); 
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

With the error changing when I change the rows.length part of the above