# The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid in JSon

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script

I am working on google scripts which can call REST API and get the data in google spreadsheets. But different Json objects work and which I am using now does not work...

At first it was giving me an error as The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. So looked to on at 
["The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid" - Google Apps Script and JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844018/the-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-the-range-are-invalid-google-apps-script-an)

And now the result is **undefined**..

Really appreciate if someone can help

```
function pullJSON(k) {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheets = ss.getSheets();
     var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

     var url = "********"; // Paste your JSON URL here
     var headers = {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",

     };

     var options = {
         "method": "GET",
         "headers": headers
     };

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // get feed
     var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
     var dataSet = dataAll;
     Logger.log(dataAll.length);
     Logger.log(k);
     Logger.log(url);

     var rows = [],
         data;
     for (var k = 0; k < Object.keys(dataSet).length; k++) {
         data = [Object.keys(dataSet)[k]];
         Logger.log(data);

         rows.push([data.total1]);} //your JSON entities here

    dataRange = sheet.getRange( 1, 1,rows.length,1); // 3 Denotes total number of entites
    dataRange.setValues(rows);
 }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what your `dataSet` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing at the moment is calling `Object.keys()` on `dataSet`.
This returns an array of strings, e.g. `["status", "data"]`.

Then you retrieve each of these keys separately and assign them as a one element array to data, so data looks like
`["status"]`, and `["data"]`.
Since `["total1]"` is an array of a string it doesn't have the `"total1"` attribute, just an element with the value equal to the name.

To get the actual total 1 value from each  object within data you can

```
dataSet.data.forEach(function(x) {
  rows.push([x.total1]);
});
```

instead of the for loop.

Comment: I am getting an error as --Cannot convert Array to Object[][] ,After using this code 

'rows.push(dataSet[[data.total1]])'
This is my Json Dataset.

'{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "*****@gmail.com": {},
      "email": "*****@gmail.com",
      "total1": *****,
      "date1": "*****"
    },
    {
      "*****2@gmail.com": {},
      "email": "*****2@gmail.com",
      "total1": *****,
      "date1": "*****",
      "total2": *****,
      "date2": "*****"
    },'

Comment: Please check my updated answer, this should work for the structure you described.

Comment: Still the same error Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 40, file...).

Comment: Sorry, of course you still need to push an array, I updated the answer

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)