# Angular ng-repeat object length

Tags: angularjs, variables

this is my object 
 
[image]

I try to display the number of images in this array but i can't figure why this is not working and it makes me crazy !

```
  <ion-item ng-click="openModal(value.$id)" ng-repeat="value in items | orderBy: '-$id' track by $index "
               class="item item-avatar" style="text-align:left">

                   <img ng-if="value['image'].image" ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{value['image'].image}}">
                   <img ng-if="!value['image'].image" ng-src="img/shelter.png">
                   <h2>{{value.nom}} </h2>
                   <p>{{value.adresse}}</p>
                   <p>{{items[0].images.length  }} Photographie(s)</p>
          </ion-item>
```

**How can i display the length of this "images" object please ?** What is missing ?

**EDIT** : `{"-KO5d2zxMY9wZd9Vp64s":true} Photographie(s)` is displaying when i put 
 `<p>{{value.images }} Photographie(s)</p>`

Comment: does `images` object have multiple object which needs to be shown on separate `ion-item`?

Comment: No, I just want to display the count of this "images" object.

Comment: does `{{value.images.length}}` not give you what you are after?

Comment: `{{value.images.length}}` No it's empty ! Nothing happens.

Comment: This is what is displaying when i have 2 images in this object : `{"-KO5d2zxMY9wZd9Vp64s":true,"-KO5pW3Msd4Jd7z_mWW_":true} Photographie(s)`

Comment: @PabloDelaNoche: look at my answer.... will Object.keys() not work for you?

Comment: It isn't an array, its just a plain object, so it won't have length, at least not the one you are expecting. The whole context of it is it is an object that is a property of an object that is the only object in an array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i figured it out ! 
I created an other filter in app.js

```
.filter('keylength', function(){
     return function(input){
     if(!angular.isObject(input)){
          return '0';
      }
     return Object.keys(input).length;
  }
})
```

and in my view :

```
<p>{{ value.images | keylength }} Photographie(s)</p>
```

And it's perfect :) Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
$scope.images_length = Object.keys(items[0].images).length;

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = {};
  $scope.items = [{"images": {"item1": "1", "item2": "2"}}];
  $scope.images_length = Object.keys($scope.items[0].images).length
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      {{images_length}}
  </div>
</div>
```

A Fiddle: 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/htt3x5Lc/

Comment: I answered to this @Thalaivar