# $scope with property says undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My controller

```
App.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.user = {};
    $scope.view = function () {
                console.log($scope.user);
                console.log($scope.user.length);
    }]);
```

My html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.lastname" />
<input type="email" ng-model="user.email" />
<input type="text" ng-model="user.address" />
<input type="email" ng-model="user.id" />
<input type="text" ng-model="user.city" />
<input type="email" ng-model="user.country" /> ---> This will be a select
```

No fields are mandatory, i have to  do a search function based on user inputs. I have to validate only one thing that user have to provide atleast one data. When i put console as above, i can see value in first one, whereas the .length console returns undefined.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no length property for an object. 
Use Object.keys length instead

```
Object.keys($scope.user).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have to first assign initial values to your model by calling an `ng-init` function. in this function first set initial values for all your models other wise you will get this undefined error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get length on an Object.  There is no length property for an object. However you can get object length using Object.key(). Check details here.

[get-js-object-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length)

Answer (score 0):

Your input type is `"email"` .

The value will `not be assigned` until you pass a valid email .

> Make type email only for email fields , let rest be text.

To get the length :

```
Object.keys($scope.user).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.user` is an object.Objects does not have length propertly.

If you want to get the number of properties of the object, then you have to use `Object.keys(object).length` function to get the length of properties of object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/shreyas_a/tbLp3bwu/) of what are you trying to achieve.

> Also, you cannot directly call the `.length` on an object. If you want
>   to get the number of properties in the object try this [SO
>   Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-or-associative-array).