# Save the result of a JSONP callback to an outer object

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsonp

after few days to break my mind and trying to solve my issue myself, I've decided to ask some help. Here is my code :

```
// -----------
// Global object
// -----------
window.myObj = window.myObj || {};
function getLocation(myObj) {
    // Location test
    // -- Mobile connection test/fix
    // -- First step => Ask on client IP
    $.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        console.warn('Fetching Accurate JSON data...');
        if (data.city !== '') {
            // Log output to console
            console.info('Location found from client ip');
            console.info(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            // myObj = data;
            // myObj.toString = function(data) {
            //  return JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
            // }
        } else {
            // -- Second step => Ask on server IP using server name
            $.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/" + window.location.host + "?callback=?", function(data) {
                // Log output to console
                console.info('Location found from server ip');
                console.info(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                // myObj = data;
                // myObj.toString = function(data) {
                //  return JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
                // }
            });
        }
    });

    return myObj;
}
console.info(getLocation(myObj));
```

What I want, is to store the result of the JSONP callback to the outer object named `myObj`.

I've tried to create the function as a closure this way:

```
window.myObj = (function () {
    // Location test
    // -- Mobile connection test/fix
    // -- First step => Ask on client IP
    $.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
        console.warn('Fetching Accurate JSON data...');
        if (data.city !== '') {
            // Log output to console
            console.info('Location found from client ip');
            return data;
        } else {
            // -- Second step => Ask on server IP using server name
            $.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/" + window.location.host + "?callback=?", function(data) {
                // Log output to console
                console.info('Location found from server ip');
                return data;
            });
        }
    });
}());
```

but it returns `undefined` everytime... As you may see my javascript skills are not so good, as my English too.

I thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I've found the solution by myself after a lot of study regarding Javascript language. Here is how I've managed my issue:

```
// -----------
// Global JS Object
// -----------
var myObj = myObj || {};

// Dependency
// Object size count function. Thanks to:
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/24457767
myObj.objSize = function(obj) {
    var count = 0;
    var key;

    if (typeof obj == "object") {
        if (Object.keys) {
            count = Object.keys(obj).length;
        } else if (window._) {
            count = _.keys(obj).length;
        } else if (window.$) {
            count = $.map(obj, function() { return 1; }).length;
        } else {
            for (key in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

// Setter method
myObj.setUserDetails = function(data) {
    this.user = {};
    this.user.details = data;
    this.user.location = {lat: data.latitude, lng: data.longitude};
    this.user.location.toString = function() {
        // Returns data as same format as Google use...
        return '(' + this.user.location.lat + ', ' + this.user.location.lng + ')';
    }.bind(this);
}

// Getter method
myObj.getUserDetails = function() {
    var _this = this;

    // -- Mobile connection test/fix
    var valid_region_codes = ['GE', 'BE', 'FR', 'VD', 'VS', 'NE', 'JU'];

    // Checking if you we've not already some user data
    if (typeof _this.user !== 'object') {
        // -- First step => Ask on client IP
        $.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(first_fetch) {
            console.warn('Fetching Accurate JSON data...');
            if (first_fetch.region_code === '') {
                // -- Empty 'region_code' => Ask on server IP using server name
                $.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/" + window.location.host + "?callback=?", function(second_fetch) {
                    // Log output to console
                    console.info('Fetch: 2');
                    console.info('Location based on server ip');
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(second_fetch, null, 2));
                    console.info(this); console.info(_this);
                    _this.setUserDetails(second_fetch);
                });
            } else {
                // -- Have 'region_code', let's proceed...
                if (valid_region_codes.indexOf(first_fetch.region_code) !== -1) {
                    // Checked 'region_code'... Valid, using client IP
                    console.info('Fetch: 1');
                    console.info('Location based on client ip');
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(first_fetch, null, 2));
                    console.info(this); console.info(_this);
                    _this.setUserDetails(first_fetch);
                } else {
                    // Checked 'region_code'... not valid, falling back to server IP
                    $.getJSON( "//freegeoip.net/json/" + window.location.host + "?callback=?", function(third_fetch) {
                        // Log output to console
                        console.info('Fetch: 3');
                        console.info('Location based on server ip');
                        console.info(JSON.stringify(third_fetch, null, 2));
                        console.info(this); console.info(_this);
                        _this.setUserDetails(third_fetch);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.warn('Using previously fetched user data...');
    }
}

// The Holy Grail method (^_^)
myObj.waitForProps = function(prop, type, timer, callback) {
    var check = setInterval(function() {
        var evil = eval(prop), evilSize = masalle.objSize(evil);
        console.info('Checking [prop] as: ' + prop + '\nTo type: ' + type +
                     '\nEach: ' + timer + 'ms\nThen exec callback:\n\t\t\t' + callback);
        if (typeof evil === type) {
            console.info('[' + prop + '] found, checking size...');
            if (evilSize > 0) {
                console.info('[' + prop + '] size: ' + evilSize);
                clearInterval(check);
                if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        }
    }, timer);
}
```

### Explanations

First, I'm calling the `getter` method `myObj.getUserDetails()` which use the `setter` method `myObj.setUserDetails()` to insert the content of the JSONP request into an object named `myObj.user`

Then, I'm calling my magic method (which is like a `waiting` method) to check the existence of the object `myObj.user`

If it's already available, I'm using it and execute the specified `callback` OR I'm iterating a `wait` timer based on the specified duration till the requested object became available then it executes the `callback`

### Usage

```
// Grab the user location
myObj.getUserDetails();

// Wait the time the required object to be created / filed
myObj.waitForProps('myObj.user', 'object', 600, function() {
    // Execute what you need there
});
```

I hope this could be useful for someone. Feel free to contact me if you know a better (and faster) way to do the same thing.

> **Known issues:**
>
> I know I've used the evil `eval` function in my magic method which
>   could led to some security issues. I hope I've used it correctly, if
>   not, please correct my code.
>
> If you're using the method `myObj.waitForProps()` in a
>   ReactJS project, you'll see that the specified duration is not respected
>   and the method iterates as fast as possible till your requested object
>   is available. Let me know if you have a tips to this issue, maybe my
>   code is just working wrong...