# How can I calculate length on the object observer in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

If I do `console.log(myObject)` the result like this :

[image]

I want to calculate the `length`

I try `myObject.lenght`, but it does not work

How can I solve this problem?

Seems this must convert first to normal object

Comment: Objects don't have a 'length'. Assuming you mean that you want to know how many properties are stored in the object you can use `Object.keys(myObject).length`

Comment: I was assuming your variable type based on the lack of information provided. Could you please show the actual contents of the variable in your question - and also not as an image as they are useless. Please copy+paste the code directly in to the question

Comment: @SuccessMan has failed to read the object at the correct time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to get object length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5533192/1369473)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JS, objects don't have a `length` property, you can use the `Object.keys(--your desired object--)` and get its length like this `Object.keys(myObject).length`. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` will return an array containing all the keys in your object, which you must pass as parameter.
Get the length of this array instead.